# "Clear data" does not clear login details

Tags: accounts, delete

I was under the impression that "clear data" clears everything, but apparently it does not. Tested with a few apps, including Facebook.

I stopped the app, cleared cache, cleared data, opened it - and by some miracle it still remembers my login details! How does it do it? How can I disable this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably also need to remove the program account details from `Settings` -> `Accounts and Backup` -> `Accounts`

It is probably there that the account details are being saved. Mainly to allow you to safely clear data (to reset the program) without the hassle of having to log back in.